# How to extract and import a subsection of an OrientDB graph

Tags: orientdb

**What I want to do**

I would like to be able to run a query like

```
traverse * from Location while $depth < 5 limit 100
```

to then import the resulting vertices and edges into a new database with the same schema as the first.

**What I've achieved**

I have a way of copying the schema by running

```
database export TestDB -includeClusterDefinitions=false -includeSecurity=false -includeRecords=false -includeIndexDefinitions=false -includeManualIndexes=false
```

and then importing it into a new database.

**Ideas**

I've looked at [OETL](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/ETL-Introduction.html) but can't figure out how to get it to do what I need.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, I used the command "export database TestDB -includeClusterDefinitions=false -includeSecurity=false -includeRecords=false -includeIndexDefinitions=false -includeManualIndexes=false"
but when I tried to import it in the new database I got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my approach to do this instead was to delete everything in the DB that wasn't in my traverse query.

```
delete vertex V where @rid not in (
    select @rid from (
        traverse * from Location while $depth < 5 limit 100
    )
)
```

This meant what was left was the schema I wanted and subset of the DB I wanted to export.

So a full export

```
export database TestDB
```

gave me what I wanted.